# trying to extract rowIds from smartsheet using node.js

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api

I am trying to iterate through and existing smartsheet to get the rowIds (which I need for setting parent/child relationships).

I am struggling :-(

Obviously I don't get the required syntax on this one.  Here is what I tried:

```
var options = {
 Id: *******************
};
var row_ids = '';

// get the sheet
smartsheet.sheets.getSheet(options) 
.then(function(sheetinfo) {
// iterate through the rows array and build comma-delimited list of row ids
for (rowIds in sheetinfo) {
    row_ids += row_ids.concat(', ');
}
});

console.log(row_ids);
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Bowow99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **Get Sheet** response, `sheetInfo` contains a collection of `rows` and each `row` object in that collection contains the property `id`. So to successfully implement the scenario you've described, you need to loop through the `sheetInfo.rows` array, and for each `row` in that array, append the value of its `id` property (followed by a comma) to create the comma-delimited string that you're attempting to build. At the end of this loop, there'll be an extra comma at the end (following the last row id you added to the string) -- so you'll need to remove it using the `substring` function.

The following code does what I've described above. Please note, I'm not a JavaScript expert -- so there may be a more efficient way to do this...but this code gets you the end result you're after: a comma-delimited string of the row Ids within the specified sheet.

```
var options = {
    id: 8337220210845572 // Id of Sheet
};

var row_ids = '';

// Get sheet
smartsheet.sheets.getSheet(options)
    .then(function(sheetInfo) {
        // iterate through rows in the sheet and build comma-delimited string of row ids
        for (var i=0; i < sheetInfo.rows.length; i++) {
            row_ids += sheetInfo.rows[i].id + ','; 
        }
        // remove the final (excess) comma from the end of the row_ids string
        row_ids = row_ids.substring(0, row_ids.length-1);
        console.log(row_ids);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```